# Is there any non-toxic and non-solvable-in-air liquid?

Tags: solutions, vapor-pressure, liquids

I want to heat the air with non-aqueous, non-toxic and non-solvable-in-air liquid (with very low relative pressure in air). Is there any such liquid exists?

It would be great if the boiling point of the liquid would be 110 °C.

Comment: Water seems to be fine. What do you mean by non-*solube* in air?

Comment: Why not just get an oil filled heater? An electric coil heats the oil in a sealed metal radiator which then radiates the heat into the room. (The oil can't get hot enough to catch something else on fire....)

Comment: As I want to heat the air in direct contact with the fluid, accordingly I concern about the liquid.

Comment: @Alchimista As we know the moisture content of air can increase by water evaporation until reaching the saturation level. I want a fluid which air does not absorb it like water vapor.

Comment: If the boiling point of the liquid is $\pu{110^\circ C}$, then by definition the liquid’s partial pressure at $\pu{110^\circ C}$ is $\pu{1013mbar}$ which means its partial pressure at lower temperatures will typically be far, far away from not noticable.

Comment: Additionally, the dependence of water partial pressure on temperature  is steeper than for most liquids with comparable boiling point, so such a liquid with the b.o. 110 Deg C may be the same or even more volatile as/than water.

Comment: I think you are under the impression that vapor pressure is a function of it's "solubility" in the head-space gas. This is not the case. For example, water has the same boiling point under air as it does under helium. Confusion is often caused here by the terminology that at 100% humidity, the air is "saturated" with water or that the air can't "hold" any more water. This makes it sound like air absorbs water vapor, as you say, which it does not.

Comment: Thanks all. I **don't need** a non-aqueous, non-toxic and non-solvable-in-air liquid **with exactly 110 °C**. I state this temperature because it's the minimum temperature which satisfies my conditions. so the boiling point of the liquid could be 500 °C or above.

Comment: I do also concern about the cost of the liquid.

Comment: Do you think the liquid desiccants would be a proper choice?

Comment: High viscosity of the liquid is a negative point for my work.

Comment: See @airhuff comment. Gases are always miscible, there is even not the concept of a solubility limit. There is not absorption of vapours by the overhead atmosphere.

Answer (score 3):

You may look at silicon Si and its derivatives. For example, the ethoxytriethylsilicane, or triethylsilicol ethyl ether is boiling at 153 °C. Or the tetraethylsilicane is also boiling at 153 °C. This last substance is used as a reference in NMR spectroscopy.